# Convert a chinese char to index for an array

Tags: arrays, trie, cjk

I'm studying the Trie data structure and i'm writing a report about them. My professor ask to me "what if i give the Trie code to chienese? What kind of changes they must make to adapt the structure to their language?"

For english version, i'm using a 26 length array. I convert char in array index in this way (str[i] - 'a'). Chinese alphabet has 21 letters. So, my opinion about the array is to leave it as english version, ignoring chars that chinese don't use. But the problem is: how can i convert chinese char in array index?

Thanks for help!

Comment: How about using a hashtable instead of an array?

Comment: I would like to leave my implementation with Array. So, if I can't convert chinese letter in index, then I will write in my report that I need to modify the structure (Using a map or hash table, like you said). But, trie Is an alternative to hash table. Why should I use hash table inside a trie? I must explain all of this things